# JTextArea not changing size vertically in MigLayout

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, layout-manager, miglayout

I have a JTextField called jta in my java program and i want it to be about 4 rows tall and I set the size when I declared the TextField and i also used jta.setSize() but I still cannot get it taller. I think it is because the MigLayout has a limit for how big a component can be in a row.

Here is a snippit of my code:

```
static JTextArea jta = new JTextArea(10, 42);
//declaring the JTextArea
    jta.setFont(inputfont);
    jta.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
    jta.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
    jta.setLineWrap(true);
    jta.setWrapStyleWord(true);
    jta.setRows(4);
//setting the jta up
panel.add(jta,"w 100%, h 100%,span,wrap");\
//adding jta to the panel
```

**Here Is What It Looks Like**

[image]

as you see it is only one line of text high, any help?

**SSCCE:**

```
import net.miginfocom.swing.MigLayout;

public class miglayout {

public static void main(String args[]) {
    MigLayout mg = new MigLayout("", "", "1");
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("jta SSCCE");
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    JLabel l1 = new JLabel("Row 1");
    JLabel l2 = new JLabel("Row 3");
    panel.setLayout(mg);
    frame.add(panel);
    JTextArea jta = new JTextArea(4, 40);
    panel.add(l1, "wrap");
    panel.add(jta, "wrap");
    panel.add(l2);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

As you can see if you run this code, even though I set the size of the JTextArea it is still one line, but if you comment out the `panel.setLayout(mg);` then it works fine.

Comment: is there a reason to use static? consider posting a (SSCCE)    [www.sscce.org] for a better sooner answer.

Comment: @nachokkI am using it in a different method to make it editable, changing colors etc. what is a SSCCE?

Comment: Short Self Contained Correct Example, you post compilable code and then people who want to help you , copy paste and can test code, and would be easy

Comment: @nachokk thank you, one problem my code is a couple hundred lines long so its not very short at all.

Comment: consider isolate your problem and post code relevant to your issue, then it will be easy to test for us and for you too.. I've never used that layout before, but layouts in general respect the preferred size rather than the size. try with `setPreferredSize()`

Comment: @nachokk okay, i will do that, one sec

Comment: @nachokk added it in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Im not an expert using this layout but thanks you post a SSCCE.

if you change

```
MigLayout mg = new MigLayout("", "", "1");
```

to

```
MigLayout mg = new MigLayout();
```

I get

[image: migLayout]